# How to change color of animation in RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I'm using a RecyclerView which contains multiple cards. When we reach the end, android shows an animation to signify that the list has ended. 
How can I change the color of that animation? Currently its showing in light blue which is the default.

Update:
There's no style attribute in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.
I have set the theme for the entire app using this:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialDrawerTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And here's the theme:

```
    <style name="MyMaterialDrawerTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar.TranslucentStatus">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    </style>
```

I've set the primary, primary_dark and the accent color.
It shows up fine in all other elements like toolbar etc. but the animation color remains blue.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the styles you have applied as part of the theme for your application. You can change the style attribute of the RecyclerView to change it. Have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html), it is one of the primary, secondary or accent colors.

Comment: I think the default colors include something blue. Try to change the colors to red, for example, and see the shadow color

Comment: You mean the color_primary? Its set to teal and the accent color is set to deep_orange as defined in the material design color palette.

Comment: I mean changing all of them to the same color to see which is the one that is providing the color

Comment: I checked with the method you suggested and i was able to find that "android:colorEdgeEffect" is the one which decides the color of the edge animation. Now the problem is that for "android:colorEdgeEffect" to work, the min API should be 21. If I try and use the supprt library and specify just"colorEdgeEffect" instead, it says no resource found. Is there any way to do this for SDK < 21?

Comment: Humm interesting. Are you using the support library tag for RecyclerView? In any case the name should be android:colorEdgeEffect although being in the support library